# WebMatrix using Bakery Template, How to disable Mobile redirect

Tags: mobile, webmatrix

I have build my first webpage using WebMatrix, and loosely using the Bakery template.  The problem is that I haven't really focused at all on the Mobile layout.  When I load my page on PC browsers, everything is great.  However, when I load on a mobile device, it is calling the _SiteLayout.Moble.cshtml instead of my normal _SiteLayout.cshtml

I can't find anywhere how it calls that .Mobile version of the cshtml, but would like for it to ignore that for now and just load the full site on a Mobile Device

Any recommendations on how to disable this for now until I can build it out?  What code or further information would be helpful to see?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On my local machine, I have tried just renaming my _SiteLayout.Mobile.cshtml, and testing with a Chrome mobile emulator.  It looks like it is forcing all mobile users to access my Full Site.  So, I think it is working.  Maybe not ideal forcing mobile users to load full content, but until I can get the functionality built out, is really my only option.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the improvements introduced by the friendly urls routing system of the Web Pages framework. There is a Microsoft tutorial lesson devoted to it: [Rendering ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites for Mobile Devices](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/rendering-aspnet-web-pages-sites-for-mobile-devices).

As far as I can tell there is no way to disable this feature, apart from deleting (or renaming as suggested by user3453337) the _SiteLayout.Mobile.cshtml file.

For a more in depth look at the Web Pages routing system read this good Mike Brind's article: [WebMatrix - URLs, UrlData and Routing for SEO](http://mikesdotnetting.com/Article/165/WebMatrix-URLs-UrlData-and-Routing-for-SEO)